# Downloading voicemail to my laptop

Tags: iphone, voicemail

How can I download my voicemail from the iPhone to my computer?

Technically, I know it is not voicemail on the iPhone - it is in ATT's phone system but you knew what I meant.

How can I download my ATT voicemail from the iPhone/iTunes to my computer?

Answer (score 18):

There is another way. Per [this instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Download-Voicemail-from-an-iPhone/step2/You-could-just-read-these-files-but-iTunes-rename/) an iTunes backup of the iPhone contains the voicemail files in these folders:

- `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/`
  Mac
- `\Documents and Settings\(username)\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\`
  Windows XP
- `\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\`
  Vista and Windows 7

However, the bad news is that these voicemail files are mixed in with a ton of other random files from your iPhone, and all the files have long, meaningless filenames with no extensions. To determine what the files are, use the `file *` command. Note that the backup must not be encrypted for this approach to work.

```
file * | grep audio
file * | grep GSM
```

(on Windows [install Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) and use the Cygwin terminal to get the file command)

The two file contents that seem likely are

```
RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 8 bit, mono 44100 Hz
Adaptive Multi-Rate Codec (GSM telephony)
```

Comment: You can also get `file` on Windows from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm), which is a lighter install than Cygwin, since you can cherry pick just the `file` utility.

Comment: To use a file, make a copy of it and rename it to have a `.amr` extension.

Answer (score 5):

I use an app called "iExplorer" (formerly iPhone Explorer).  It basically lets you reach into the phone to download, modify, replace, or add a file in any (or almost any) directory within the file structure.

http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

Comment: Your phone has to be jailbroken for iExplorer to access voicemail files.  Apparently the paid version (Phone to Mac or Phone to PC) will copy voicemail off a 'regular' iPhone: http://www.macroplant.com/phonetomac/

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it in iTunes, and you have to be jailbroken to do it. [Here's](http://lifehacker.com/399404/how-to-transfer-iphone-voicemail-to-your-computer) a good tutorial.

1. Jailbreak phone
2. Install OpenSSH from Cydia
3. Install CyberDuck (or another SSH program) to your computer
4. SSH into your iPhone from the computer ([here's](http://www.simonblog.com/2009/05/17/how-to-use-ssh-to-transfer-file-on-iphone/) how)
5. Navigate to `/private/var/mobile/Library/Voicemail/`
6. Copy the desired `.amr` files

Answer (score 3):

Or use Google voice and you can get them through the browser or emailed to you.

Comment: These are existing voicemail messages.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Phone View](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) for this purpose and it works flawlessly. You do not have to jailbreak your phone for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Google Voice number that I just forward important voicemails to.

To do this in a typical voicemail system, you'd press 6 for more options, then 2 to forward it.

You can keep them in your Google account pretty much as long as you want, or you can simply download them at will.

I hope this is helpful.